# How To Call WekaSharp Commands From C#

Tags: c#, f#, data-mining, weka

Thank you all for you help on my F# and C# question and am really beginning to enjoy the fruits of the learning. I have asked a question like this before and I know these are on the line of the purposes of this forum, but I think this is useful and would provide some help to all us F# data miners out there :-). I am utilizing Yin Zhu's WekaSharp for my experiments and am interested in the rates of computation between F# and C#. I have written a snippet based on his example in the F# and would like to make its like in C# but am not sure how to approach it. Yin Zhu has create the same code to access these functions from the C# called WekaCSharp but the example he provides does not really touch on this operation. I hate to keep bugging him with my menial questions so if anyone has the time and is willing here is the F# script:

```ml
(* K-Means cluster Algorithm *)

// load the data set
let sonar = 
    System.IO.Path.Combine(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__,  @"..\..\data\KDDCup99.arff")
    |> Dataset.readArff
    |> Dataset.setClassIndexWithLastAttribute

// set different parameters 
let Cs = [0.01; 0.1; 1.; 10.; 50.; 100.; 500.; 1000.; 2000.; 5000. ]

// make the tasks with the parameter set
let tasks = 
    Cs
    |> List.map (fun c -> Parameter.KNN.DefaultPara)
    |> List.map (fun p -> CrossValidation(3, sonar, ClassifierType.KNN, p))

Profile.tic()
// the accuracy result
let results = 
    tasks
    |> Eval.evalBulkClassify
    |> List.map Eval.getAccuracy

Profile.toc("sequential time: ")


Profile.tic()
let resultsParallel = 
    tasks
    |> Eval.evalBulkClassifyParallel
    |> List.map Eval.getAccuracy

Profile.toc("parallel (PSeq) time: ")
```

Again, I apologize if I am streaching the intent of this forum but this would be greatly useful for all us learning to use Weka in .NET . Here is what I have so far:

```
class Program
    {

        static void Classify()
        {
            Instances dataSetForTrain = new Instances(new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(@"C:\Users\Deines\Documents\School\Software\WekaSharp2012\data\iris.arff")));
            dataSetForTrain.setClassIndex(dataSetForTrain.numAttributes() - 1);

            string options = @"-P 100 -S 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -- -M 2 -V 0.0010 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1";
            Bagging model = new Bagging();
            model.setOptions(options.Split(' '));
            model.buildClassifier(dataSetForTrain);


            // test the instances from iris.arff
            Instances dataSetForTest = new Instances(new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(@"C:\Users\Deines\Documents\School\Software\WekaSharp2012\data\iris.arff")));

            dataSetForTest.setClassIndex(dataSetForTest.numAttributes() - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataSetForTest.numInstances(); i++)
            {
                var inst = dataSetForTest.instance(i);
                int label = (int)model.classifyInstance(inst);
                System.Console.WriteLine(label);
            }

        }


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Classify();
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should really post the specific part that you are having trouble translating to C#, as well as what you have tried.

Comment: Yes You are correct sir. Here is what I have created thusfar, what is missing is the parellel execution and the different parameters:

Comment: I am now worried that the question was overfocused on the WekaSharp aspect instead of what was really needed. Where the difficulty is in this process is performing parallel and serial evulation in weka through C# and calculating the percent correct usinging the Weka call. I am tring to get the call weka.classifiers.Evaluation.pctCorrect(); working in this context. Thank you.