# Weka In C# Write Lables and Data to an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, data-mining, weka

I have asked some questions on this chunck of code and have gotten som help on concurrent execution with parts as well as general structure. I had one more question on this in the weka context. I would like to output the results of the lables onto the data into an array so that I might put it into a plot later. Here is the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using weka.classifiers.meta;
using weka.classifiers.functions;
using weka.core;
using java.io;
using weka.clusterers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

// From http://weka.wikispaces.com/IKVM+with+Weka+tutorial

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("J48 in C#");
        classifyTest();
    }

    const int percentSplit = 66;
    public static void classifyTest()
    {
        try
        {

            Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch1.Start();

            weka.core.Instances insts = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader(@"C:\Users\Deines\Documents\School\Software\WekaSharp2012\data\sonar.arff"));
            insts.setClassIndex(insts.numAttributes() - 1);

            weka.classifiers.Classifier cl = new weka.classifiers.trees.J48();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Performing " + percentSplit + "% split evaluation.");

            // Stop timing
            stopwatch1.Stop();

            // Write result
            System.Console.WriteLine("Load The Data Set: {0}",
              stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch2.Start();

            //randomize the order of the instances in the dataset.
            weka.filters.Filter myRandom = new weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.Randomize();
            myRandom.setInputFormat(insts);
            insts = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(insts, myRandom);

            int trainSize = insts.numInstances() * percentSplit / 100;
            int testSize = insts.numInstances() - trainSize;
            weka.core.Instances train = new weka.core.Instances(insts, 0, trainSize);

            // Stop timing
            stopwatch2.Stop();

            // Write result
            System.Console.WriteLine("Tasks With Parameter Set: {0}",
              stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            Stopwatch stopwatch3 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch3.Start();

            cl.buildClassifier(train);
            int numCorrect = 0;
            for (int i = trainSize; i < insts.numInstances(); i++)
            {
                weka.core.Instance currentInst = insts.instance(i);
                double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(currentInst);
                if (predictedClass == insts.instance(i).classValue())
                    numCorrect++;
            }
            // Stop timing
            stopwatch3.Stop();

            // Write result
            System.Console.WriteLine("Sequential Time: {0}",
              stopwatch3.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Stopwatch stopwatch4 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch4.Start();

            //Parallel Calculation
            cl.buildClassifier(train);
            int numCorrectpara = 0;
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(trainSize, insts.numInstances(), i =>
            {
                weka.core.Instance currentInst = insts.instance(i);
                double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(currentInst);
                if (predictedClass == insts.instance(i).classValue())
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref numCorrectpara);
            });

            // Stop timing
            stopwatch4.Stop();

            // Write result
            System.Console.WriteLine("Parallel Time: {0}",
              stopwatch3.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            System.Console.WriteLine(numCorrect + " out of " + testSize + " correct (" +
           (double)((double)numCorrect / (double)testSize * 100.0) + "%)");


            System.Console.WriteLine(numCorrectpara + " out of " + testSize + " correct (" +
           (double)((double)numCorrectpara/ (double)testSize * 100.0) + "%)");

        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The section where the array should be made is as follows and I think a line world be something like this:

```
    cl.buildClassifier(train);
    int numCorrect = 0;
    string[,] array = new string[38, insts.numInstances()];

    for (int i = trainSize; i < insts.numInstances(); i++)
    {
        weka.core.Instance currentInst = insts.instance(i);
        double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(currentInst);
        string value = array[currentInst, predictedClass];
        Console.WriteLine(value);

        if (predictedClass == insts.instance(i).classValue())
            numCorrect++;
    }
```

I get the error code:
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'weka.core.Instance' to 'int'    C:\Users\Deines\Documents\School\Software\WekaCSharp2012\Class1.cs  77  38  WekaSample
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   C:\Users\Deines\Documents\School\Software\WekaCSharp2012\Class1.cs  77  51  WekaSample

I am assuming a dataset of 38 elements and a length as defined by instances. I am still fairly new to C# as I have spent most of my life in functional programming so I apologize for the ignorance of my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question based on that information. "does not seem to work" is not enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: @nvoigt I apologize I did not mean to be so vauge I will get the error code up to clear up what I mean, thank you for the advice :-).

Answer (score 0):

First, your array is a two dimensional array of strings. The cells in an array are accessible using integer indices.
It seems you are using 2 types which are not integers as indices. One is of type `weka.core.Instance` the other is of type `double`. If these are indeed your indices then you should translate them into integers somehow or use a different "container".

Second, you wrote "the array should be made". Unless some code is missing, it seems that the array is empty. And your assignment in this line(if the indices error was corrected) will always return an empty string:

```
string value = array[currentInst, predictedClass];
```

Reading this again a few more times, I think I understand what you wanted.
Assuming that the information you want to store in the array is assigned to `predictedClass`, and assuming you want to store the result in the array in the order of the instances, this is what you should do:

You should change the array type to an array of double with one dimension.

```
double[] array = new double[insts.numInstances()];
```

now I also assume you want results from all the instances so let's start the loop from 0. It is fine of course to store the results of some of the instances, in that case, some of the array will be empty and maybe it will be better to just use a smaller array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < insts.numInstances(); i++)
```

next we take the an instance, then we get the 'predictedClass' and store the result in the array:

```
weka.core.Instance currentInst = insts.instance(i);
double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(currentInst);
array[i] = predictedClass;
//.. the rest of the loop
```

if you wanted to store the class value you can use this assignment instead:

```
array[i] = insts.instance(i).classValue();
```

Comment: Would there be a better way such as a map of the instance to the predictedClass?

Comment: A most excellent idea, this was very helpful advise and instructive as well. I will give this a go in my code and see what we get. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use a dictionary where the key is of type weka.core.Instance, and the value is of type double. This way you can find the value without having to rely on the index of the instance being the same. If that sounds better I can show you how.

Comment: I appriciate the offer, in this case my purpose is to make the code I have created here as close as possible to the F# code I created for this same purpose ( my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204678/how-to-call-wekasharp-commands-from-c-sharp). I would be very interested on learning on how to do this in a dictionary, but I understand if there are other fish to fry :-).

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually trying to achieve so I cannot tell you what is the prefered way, but here you can find good explanation and examples of how to use C# Dictionaries: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary